# "Zaycher" or "Zehcher" Lemikdash K'Hillel for Korech?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, korech

The text of every *Hagadah* that I have seen has the beginning text for כורך as:

זֵכֶר לְמִקְדָּשׁ כְּהִלֵּל.

using a *tzere* under the ז.

A *Chassid* told me last Shabbat that at a Seder he attended a few years ago, his host made כורך **twice**. Once saying זֵכֶר and a second time saying זֵֶכֶר with a segol (as "zecher" to rhyme with "becher").

I told him that I didn't think that 2nd version was necessary. As far as I understand, in Hebrew, verbs having a segol in the 1st letter convert it to a tzere when it is used as an adjective form as it is being used here.

Is this a correct analysis? Are there any minhagim or any opinions that state that it should be done twice because of a doubt of how this word should be pronounced?

Comment: Why didn't he just say "Zecher Zaycher" Amalek, oops, L'Mikdash

Comment: Did he eat it twice or only say it twice? Perhaps he was just a jolly fellow.

Comment: @GershonGold from what I understood from the Chassid, he ate twice.

Comment: Wow. Then he must have a massive BMI. I have no doubt that he was Kibitzing.

Comment: @GershonGold Or a reasonably sized Kezayit.

Comment: Hopefully this was done as a joke, as there is no din amira per se that would even open the door to such a chumra. The proclamation is simply a wherewithal to convey information. The same info. is conveyed with a tzerei or a seggol.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is no such Minhag. As it is once one ate Matzo, Marror, Korech, and did Shulachan Orech it is often not easy to eat the Afikomen, and the [Beer Hataiv 477:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=174) says that one should not be eating the Afikomen as Achila Gasa. If one ate an additional Korech sandwich it would make the Afikomen into Achila Gasa.

Comment: I don't understand your logic at all. An additional Korech sandwhich doesn't necessarily fill you up. Just skip the second bowl of soup. Many people serve extra maror and matza during the meal anyway.

Comment: Supplemental to what @DoubleAA pointed out, the Ba'er Hetev mentions that Achila Gasa is a form of "ta'avah" (lust). I.e. - he eats a lot because he enjoys eating. In this case, the man ate two korechs b / c he believed that the 1st one may not have fulfilled the mitzvah! And, seriously, why do I suspect that you and other commenters feel that you have to mock a Chassid who does feel this way, just b/c you disagree with his practice or find it strange? Did you see me imply any mocking in my question?

Comment: @DanF: I am not mocking the fellow. Whoever told you this was mocking you.